# Jquery Redirect

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to be able to re-direct my page if this div contains this message:

```
<DIV class=FinalMessageDialog id=DialogFinalMessage><DIV>
The form has been closed.
</DIV></DIV>
```

Thanks in advance, if it makes any difference I am trying to acomplish this in a SharePoint web part and I have already tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($('#DialogFinalMessage').children().length>0)
{
 window.location.href = "<Desired destination page URL>";
}
 });
```

Comment: Is the webpart rendered as an iframe? You code is fine BTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#DialogFinalMessage > div').html().length>0){
        window.location.href = "<Desired destination page URL>"
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BtUFa/2/

Should give a nice 404 because it has redirected

Comment: When editing it your code I get this error in firebug:TypeError: $(...).html(...) is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

if($('#DialogFinalMessage').html().length>0){

Comment: This does not work anyways, the length is ALWAYS greater than zero because it contains <div/>

Comment: I changed it to > div well spotted

Comment: This works in firefox but doesn't in IE 8... any ideas? (unfortunately as a business we are restricted to using IE 8 for most of our applications)

Comment: When including your javascript make sure it says text/javascript NOT application/javascript as IE8 doesn't support that

Comment: Still getting the same error: "Objected Expected" on this code:    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">
 
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#DialogFinalMessage > div').html().length>0){
        window.location.href = "<Desired destination page URL>"
   }
});</script>

Comment: Have you made sure there are " around the class and id?
<div class="FinalMessageDialog" id="DialogFinalMessage">

Comment: I can't change that bit of the HTML, that's generated by SharePoint :(

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
if ($('#DialogFinalMessage>div').text() === 'The form has been closed.') {
    window.location.href = "<Desired destination page URL>";
}
```

Comment: Copy from who? Seems more like what the OP asked for in this answer than mine